# Data is not populating in the ngTable

Tags: angularjs

Iam new to angularJS. Iam tring to implement a table with pagination using ngTable.

Initially I tried with ngTableParams injection ('n' is lowecase), it was not supporting in the angular at all.

As my understanding I need to relook the **getData** function implementation in the controller
(Not getting any error in the browser console.)

Attaching the code below.

### Controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('settings')
    .controller('SettingsAcademicYearCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'AcademicYearFactory', 'NgTableParams',
        function ($scope, $http, AcademicYearFactory,  NgTableParams) {

            var tableData = [];

            $scope.usersTable = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 3
            }, {
                //total: $scope.users.length,
                total: tableData.length,
                getData: function (params) {

                    $http.get('modules/settings/controllers/data.json').then(function (response) {
                        tableData = response.data.users;
                        //$defer.resolve(tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        params.total(tableData.length);
                        return response.data;

                    });
                }
            });

        }]);
```

### data.json

```
{
  "users":[{
                "id": 1,
                "first_name": "Philip",
                "last_name": "Kim",
                "email": "pkim0@mediafire.com",
                "country": "Indonesia",
                "ip_address": "29.107.35.8"
            },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "first_name": "Judith",
                    "last_name": "Austin",
                    "email": "jaustin1@mapquest.com",
                    "country": "China",
                    "ip_address": "173.65.94.30"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "first_name": "Julie",
                    "last_name": "Wells",
                    "email": "jwells2@illinois.edu",
                    "country": "Finland",
                    "ip_address": "9.100.80.145"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "first_name": "Gloria",
                    "last_name": "Greene",
                    "email": "ggreene3@blogs.com",
                    "country": "Indonesia",
                    "ip_address": "69.115.85.157"
                },
                {
                    "id": 50,
                    "first_name": "Andrea",
                    "last_name": "Greene",
                    "email": "agreene4@fda.gov",
                    "country": "Russia",
                    "ip_address": "128.72.13.52"
                }]
}
```

### html

```
   <div>
        <table ng-table="usersTable"  class="table table-striped">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in data">
                <td data-title="'Id'">
                    {{user.id}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'First Name'">
                    {{user.first_name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Last Name'">
                    {{user.last_name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'e-mail'">
                    {{user.email}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Country'">
                    {{user.country}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'IP'">
                    {{user.ip_address}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And also included all the necessary js and css files in the main html page.

Can someone help me to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getData` should return `$http.get()`

Comment: tried...not working :(

Comment: Update your question then, because it's definitely wrong to return `undefined` in `getData` method. Try to locate the source of the problem. First, check if table works with static data (without async fetching with `getData`). Then check if data is actually here: `'modules/settings/controllers/data.json'`